# Проверка данных из базы. ajax, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<script>

function checkAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    $("#Check").on("click", function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "check_availability.php",
            data: {
                username: $("#username").val(),
                date_order: $("#date_order").val(),
                time_order: $("#time_order").val(),
                table_num: $("#table_num").val()
            },

            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#user-availability-status").html(data);

            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    }
    );
}
</script>
```

**Обновление**

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM name WHERE name='" . $_POST{"username"} . "'");
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $user_count = $row[0];
  if($user_count>0) {
      echo "<span class='status-not-available'> Username Not Available.</span>";
  }else{
      echo "<span class='status-available'> Username Available.</span>";
  }
}
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function checkAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "check_availability.php",
    data:'username='+$("#username").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: изначально эта форма для проверки логина из базы. Есть текстовое поле куда вводится логин и идёт проверка из базы. мне надо, чтобы не только логин проверялся. Онлайн бронирование. есть дата, время, и номер стола, если дата, время и номер, заняты, то пользователю выводится сообщение.

Comment: data(ну это ясно),field3(столы чекбоксы),sch(выбор времени селект )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не зная сохраняются дата и время в одно поле бд или нет предположим, что дата и время сохраняются в два поля.

Исходя из предположений решение такое:

```
<div id="frmCheckUsername">
    <label>date_order:</label>
    <input name="date_order" type="text" id="date_order">
    <label>time_order:</label>
    <input name="time_order" type="text" id="time_order">
    <label>table_num:</label>
    <input name="table_num" type="text" id="table_num">
    <label>Check Username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username">
    <span id="user-availability-status"></span> 
    <button id="Check">Проверить</button>
</div>

$("#Check").on("click", function(){
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: "check_availability.php", 
        data: { username: $("#username").val(), 
                date_order: $("#date_order").val(), 
                time_order: $("#time_order").val(), 
                table_num: $("#table_num").val() 
        },
        type: "POST", 
        success:function(data){ 
            $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
        }, 
        error:function (){} 
    });
});

<?php
...
if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["date_order"]) && !empty($_POST["time_order"]) && !empty($_POST["table_num"])) {
    $sql = "
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM name 
        WHERE 
            name='" . $_POST["username"] . "' AND 
            date_order='" . $_POST["date_order"] . "' AND 
            time_order='" . $_POST["time_order"] . "' AND 
            table_num='" . $_POST["table_num"] . "'
    ";
           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
               echo "<span class='status-not-available'> Username Not Available.</span>"; 
           }
           else{ 
               echo "<span class='status-available'> Username Available.</span>"; 
          } 
}
else{
    echo "Одно из полей пустое";
}
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30155/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-----ajax-mysql).